# Twitter share button does not appear on my website

Tags: html, twitter

I generated HTML (on publish.twitter.com) to create a twitter share button on my website.  The button does not show on the website.  The code is below.  I added the "glurb" paragraph to see whe it appears.  It does.  I also put the required script in my scripts section.  The code is

```
   <div>
       <p>glurb</p>
       <a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large" data-url="http://www.findthemasks.com" data-via="@susancrayne" data-related="@findthemasks" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
   </div>
```

And the script is:

```
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: It appears in Safari but not in Chrome

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site?